# JMETER creates multiple process threads even for Single Thread run

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am running a simple JMETER file with one Thread Group with Single user.

when I look at the background ps -eL | grep jmeter

I get more than 30+ threads for that PID as below.
Any suggestion why this is occuring and if there is a way to prevent this?[image]

output of ps -eL  | grep jmeter

6380  6380 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6381 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6382 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6383 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6384 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6385 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6386 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6387 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6388 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6389 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6390 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6391 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6392 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6393 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6394 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6395 pts/0    Rl+    0:02 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6396 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6397 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6398 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6399 pts/0    Sl+    0:03 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6402 pts/0    Sl+    0:02 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6403 pts/0    Sl+    0:02 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6404 pts/0    Sl+    0:02 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6405 pts/0    Sl+    0:03 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6406 pts/0    Sl+    0:02 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6407 pts/0    Sl+    0:02 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6408 pts/0    Sl+    0:03 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6409 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6410 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6411 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6412 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6413 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6414 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6415 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6416 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6417 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6419 pts/0    Sl+    1:34 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6420 pts/0    Sl+    1:05 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx
6380  6421 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/manh/inhouse_apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t jmx/retail/dev/test_concurrency.jmx

Answer (score 0):

One JMeter instance = one Java process, the number of internal threads can be viewed using i.e. [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

If you're seeing more than one Java process it means that you (or someone else) started another JMeter instance in [non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

[image]

You might also want to consider upgrading to the latest JMeter version (which is [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) as of now) as you're supposed to be using the latest version of JMeter according to [Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) user manual chapter